# writing text on imagebutton

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I have two ImageButtons and I want show a text and a image on it. But when I try to run it on Emulator the button have image but without the text. please How can I show the text.

My Xml code:

```
I<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btnbluee"
    android:text="start monitoring"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnorange"
     android:text="start activity"/>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you expect any text to be displayed on your buttons... Nothing in your layout tells it to do so and imagebuttons only display images, not text anyways

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, you are right l wil update my question.

Comment: `android:text` is not an attribute of an ImageButton, which is an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). See the XML attribute section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of `ImageButton`

> Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user.

Plus, `ImageButton extends ImageView` in the source code whereas `Button extends TextView`, meaning that you can't display text on an `ImageButton`.

In that case, you can simply change your `ImageButton` to `Button`, and it should work.

Sidenote: You set the `android:src` attribute of an `ImageButton` to show an image, anyway, so you weren't implementing that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageButton` is a subclass of `ImageView` and it cannot show text.
You can use `Button`  instead. It can have both -

1. Text to show using `android:text`
2. Picture as the background using `android:background`